# How by ajax return a view blade in controller?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, controller

I want to return a view using ajax in the controller regardless of response ajax.
for this state refresh the page

Comment: You don't really care about ajax, your route will return a view anyway, how the route is called is not really your concern. Also you will need to develop your question a lot more, one line is a bit short for a question, it will get closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the render() function.

```
$html = view('view.name')->render();
```

After that just return it.

```
return response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $html ]);
```